# Counter inside nested loops with OpenMP

Tags: c, global-variables, openmp, nested-loops

I use counters in my [c program](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Julia_set_for_f(z)%3Dz2_over_(z9-z%2B0.025).png) for making raster image to see  image statistic :  relative size of each basin ( [pixel counting](https://www.mrob.com/pub/muency/pixelcounting.html))

My program is long so I have made [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

First progrm withou OpenMP which shows what I want to achive ( number of all pixels):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{

    int x;
    int xMax = 100;
    int y;
    int yMax = 100;
    
    
    
    int i= 0; 

    for (x = 0; x < xMax; x++) {

        for (y = 0; y < yMax; y++)
            {i++;}
        }

    printf("i = %d \t xMax*yMax = %d\n", i, xMax*yMax);
    return 0;
}
```

It counts pixels(x,y) properly:

```
 i = xMax*yMax
```

When I add OpenMP then it is not so easy, but reduction helps

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>        // OpenMP


int i= 0; 

int main()
{

    int x;
    int xMax = 1000;
    int y;
    int yMax = 1000;
    int all = xMax*yMax;
    
    
    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) schedule(dynamic) reduction(+:i)
    for (x = 0; x < xMax; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < yMax; y++)
            {i++;}
        }

    printf("i = %d = %f*(xMax*yMax) \t where xMax*yMax = %d\n", i, (double)i/all,  all);
    return 0;
}
```

When I hide counter inside another function then counter is not updated properly

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>        // OpenMP


int i= 0; 



void P(){

 i++;

}




int main()
{

    int x;
    int xMax = 1000;
    int y;
    int yMax = 1000;
    int all = xMax*yMax;
    
    
    
    

    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) schedule(dynamic) reduction(+:i)
    for (x = 0; x < xMax; x++) {

        for (y = 0; y < yMax; y++)
            {P();}
        }

    printf("i = %d = %f*(xMax*yMax) \t where xMax*yMax = %d\n", i, (double)i/all,  all);
    return 0;
}
```

Now :

```
gcc p.c -Wall -fopenmp
./a.out
i = 437534 = 0.437534*(xMax*yMax)    where xMax*yMax = 1000000
```

**Problem : counter inside function is not updated properly**

**Question : What should I change to update counter properly ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `reduction(+:i)` clause creates a local variable `i`, and you are supposed to change this local variable. In your code, however,  you increment the global one by calling function `P`, which is not thread safe (it has a race condition when incrementing it). So, you just have to make sure that you increment the local `i` when calling function `P`:

```
    void P(int& i){
       i++;
    }

    //in main:
    for (y = 0; y < yMax; y++)
            {P(i);}
```

Another (but slower) option is to make function `P` threadsafe by using an atomic operation. In this case you do not need reduction at all:

```
void P(){
#pragma omp atomic
 i++;
}
```