# How to return a value from a function which needs to use parrallel programming using openmp in C language?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

static double num = 1;

double func1(){
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
        num += 1;
        for (int j=0; j<100; j++){
            num -= 1;
            for (int k=0; k<100; k++){
                num += 1;
                if (num == 1000){
                    return num;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(10)
    {
        double num2 = func1();
    }
    printf("%lf", num2);
    return 0;
}

/*
Compiles with: gcc fileName.c -o fileName -openmp
Executes with: ./fileName
// Note: in the terminal
*/
```

The above code when compiled gets stuck in an endless loop or something it does not exit.
I tried "#pragma omp parallel for" but it throws out an error.
I wonder if it works if I collapse the loop into one.
Would really appreciate help. Thanks.`

Comment: There are data race in your code. Different threads read/write a global variable (`num`). It is not clear for me what your goal is. Can you clarify?

Comment: Really bad code. 1. It can not compile because `num2` is local. 2. Your function generates a warning that there are code paths that return void. 3. Why do you return `num` when it's global anyway? 4. Do not use global variables. 5. Your `printf` is missing a newline.

Comment: I will redo the script by next week, it is a simplified version of a more complex problem. Signed up here in stack overflow just today.

Answer (score 0):

This is a no-show: all your threads try updating simultaneously the `num` global variable. This is a so-called "race condition". Not only the final result is unpredictable, but this slows down everything.

As a rule of thumb, in multithreaded code do not use global and/or static variables, unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: `num2` is free from race condition (private variable), but its scope is the parallel block (so the code cannot be compiled)

Comment: @Laci indeed I missed that is was declared within the parallel region

Comment: Lets say I add "#pragma omp critical" on all num. I think problems like this cannot be done on openmp at all. I simply cannot find any document where they return a value from a function through openmp. Maybe  I need to try posix threads instead.

Comment: @TaizanLama OpenMP is not the problem: whatever thread system you are using you can simply not updating a global variable from different threads like this. `critical` or `atomic` pragmas won't really solve anything here, as the result will be still unpredictable. And I agree with Laci, the code you have displayed can simply not be compiled, so this is not the one you have run. It would compile and run if the `printf` was inside the parallel region.

Comment: @TaizanLama  Note that your code has other issues besides the ones mentioned above:  1) there is no `return` statement in `func1` after the loops, 2) you compare floating point values without considering the numeric precision, but the most important question: What is your goal?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has as race condition. Interesting, adding `reduction(+:num)` to the parallel clause doesn't solve much. You break at `1000` but I get results (if I make `num2` global to the main) that are approximately `1000+nthreads`. Big question is: what is this supposed to do?

For the rest I have some comments: 1. It can not compile because num2 is local. 2. Your function generates a warning that there are code paths that return void. 3. Why do you return num when it's global anyway? 4. Do not use global variables. 5. Your printf is missing a newline.

Comment: It is not surprising that `reduction(+:num)` does not solve the issue, because scopes are different:  function `func1` uses the global `num`, not the local one created by the reduction clause in the parallel region.

Comment: @Laci I think this may require very careful parsing of the standard. Reductions always use a local variable, but it comes from some outer environment. Usually that's the block containing the reduction clause, but in this case it's every further outer.

Comment: Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68638643/counter-inside-nested-loops-with-openmp/68640077#68640077). I think it is exactly the same situation.